# pycurl infinite loop and getopt issue

Tags: python, getopt, pycurl

I am new to coding and and trying to learn as I go.

I'm trying to create a python script that will grab and print all HEADERS from a list of urls in a txt file.

It seems to be getting there but im stuck in an infinite loop with one of the urls and I have no idea why and for some reason the "-h", or "--help" wont return the `usage()`. Any help would be appreciated.

Below is what I have so far:

```
 #!/usr/bin/python

 import pycurl
 import cStringIO
 import sys, getopt

 buf = cStringIO.StringIO()
 c = pycurl.Curl()

 def usage():
     print "-h --help, -i --urlist, -o --proxy"
     sys.exit()

 def main(argv):
    iurlist = None
    proxy = None
    try:
       opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv,"hi:o:t",["help", "iurlist=","proxy="])
       if not opts:
         print "No options supplied"
         print "Type -h for help"
         sys.exit()
    except getopt.GetoptError as err:
       print str(err)
       usage()
       sys.exit(2)

    for opt, arg in opts:
       if opt == ("-h", "--help"):
          usage()
          sys.exit()
       elif opt in ("-i", "--iurlist"):
           iurlist = arg
       elif opt in ("-o", "--proxy"):
           proxy = arg
       else:
          assert False, "Unhandeled option"

 with open(iurlist) as f:
      iurlist = f.readlines()
      print iurlist

 try:
      for i in iurlist:
            c.setopt(c.URL, i)
            c.setopt(c.PROXY, proxy)
            c.setopt(c.HEADER, 1)
            c.setopt(c.FOLLOWLOCATION, 1)
            c.setopt(c.MAXREDIRS, 30)
            c.setopt(c.USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0')
            c.setopt(c.TIMEOUT, 8)
            c.setopt(c.CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5)
            c.setopt(c.NOBODY, 1)
            c.setopt(c.PROXY, proxy)
            c.setopt(c.WRITEFUNCTION, buf.write)
            c.setopt(c.SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0)
            c.perform()
            print buf.getvalue()
            buf.close

  except pycurl.error, error:
       errno, errstr = error
       print 'An error has occurred: ', errstr

 if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

**This is the latest code:**

```
 #!/usr/bin/python

 import pycurl
 import cStringIO
 import sys, getopt

 c = pycurl.Curl()

 def usage():
     print "-h --help, -i --urlist, -o --proxy"
     print "Example Usage: cURLdect.py -i urlist.txt -o http://192.168.1.64:8080"
     sys.exit()

 def main(argv):
    iurlist = None
    proxy = None
    try:
       opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv,"hi:o:t",["help", "iurlist=","proxy="])
       if not opts:
         print "No options supplied"
         print "Type -h for help"
         sys.exit()
    except getopt.GetoptError as err:
       print str(err)
       usage()
       sys.exit(2)

    for opt, arg in opts:
       if opt in ("-h", "--help"):
          usage()
          sys.exit()
       elif opt in ("-i", "--iurlist"):
          iurlist = arg
       elif opt in ("-o", "--proxy"):
          proxy = arg
       else:
          assert False, "Unhandeled option"

    with open(iurlist) as f:
         iurlist = f.readlines()
         print iurlist

    try:
         for i in iurlist:
            buf = cStringIO.StringIO()
            c.setopt(c.WRITEFUNCTION, buf.write)
            c.setopt(c.PROXY, proxy)
            c.setopt(c.HEADER, 1)
            c.setopt(c.FOLLOWLOCATION, 1)
            c.setopt(c.MAXREDIRS, 300)
            c.setopt(c.USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0')
            c.setopt(c.TIMEOUT, 8)
            c.setopt(c.CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5)
            c.setopt(c.NOBODY, 1)
            c.setopt(c.SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0)
            c.setopt(c.URL, i)
            c.perform()
            print buf.getvalue()
            buf.close()
    except pycurl.error, error:
         errno, errstr = error
         print 'An error has occurred: ', errstr

 if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Comment: I have worked out a way to fix the getopt issues regarding the usage().  I made the following code changes `for opt, arg in opts:
      if opt == "-h":
         usage()
         sys.exit()
      elif opt in ("--help"):
         usage()
         sys.ext()`

Comment: You're misusing ``buf``. ``buf.close`` without braces doesn't close it, returns a function.

Comment: @xbello Sorry so how should I close it?

Comment: Using ``buf.close()``. BUT take care, because you're opening it out of the loop and closing it inside. Open the buffer before ``c.setop(c.URL, i)``.

Comment: @xbello ok just to confirm the opening is the c.setopt(c.WRITEFUNCTION, buf.write) line?

Comment: @xbello ok got it ;) thanks for your help. if you put an answer in I can give you the "correct" answer

Comment: @xbello strangley enough it worked first time round after moving the open into the loop, but now its failing again :( sigh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are learning, pycurl may not be the best option. They asume you're familiar with the libcurl library. From http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/:

> PycURL is targeted at an *advanced* developer - if you need dozens of concurrent, fast and reliable connections or any of the sophisticated features listed above then PycURL is for you.
>
> The main drawback of PycURL is that it is a relatively thin layer over libcurl without any of those nice Pythonic class hierarchies. This means it has a somewhat *steep learning curve* unless you are already familiar with libcurl's C API.

This is how they do a multi-fetch: https://github.com/pycurl/pycurl/blob/master/examples/retriever-multi.py

---

To fetch the headers *a la python*, install the `requests` library, and just do:

```
for url in list_of_urls:
    r = requests.get(url)
    print r.headers
```

To deal with command line arguments, use the `argparser` in the batteries included with python.

Answer (score 0):

You're using

> if opt == ("-h", "--help"):

for the help option, but

> if opt **in** (....)

for all the other options.
`opt` is either `-h` or `--help`, but not both, so you need to use `in` to check if `opt` is either of it as well.

Comment: Thanks will wait for other issue answer and select answers accordingly